# Extract the url from the browser in javascript

Tags: javascript, outlook-addin, domexception

I'm building an outlook add-in that shares contents of a mail to a messaging system.

It requires IDP authentication to login to the messaging system. A pop up appears for the authentication purpose. When the user enters the credentials in the pop up window, the user gets redirected to another page and URL gets changed.

This URL has a token id which I want to extract so I can use it in my code for further API calls. When i tried, I received the following error:

> Uncaught DOMException: An attempt was made to break through the security policy of the user agent

Is there a way to extract the new URL without getting the above error ?

```
function determineAuthenticationMethodAndRedirect(data, tenantId) {
        if (data.IdentityProvider.Enabled) {
            console.log("Identity Provider authentication is enabled");
            openPopup(Office.context.roamingSettings.get("userInput") + "/Apps/Erp/Home/", tenantId);
        } else if (data.TokenAuthentication.Enabled) {
            console.log("Token-based authentication is enabled");
            window.location.href = "ep-collab-login.js";
        } else if (data.BasicAuthentication.Enabled) {
            console.log("Basic authentication is enabled");
        } else {
            console.log("No supported authentication method is enabled");
        }
    }

    function openPopup(url, tenantId) {
        var popupWidth = 600;
        var popupHeight = 400;
        var popupSettings = `width=${popupWidth},height=${popupHeight},top=${(window.innerHeight - popupHeight) / 2},left=${(window.innerWidth - popupWidth) / 2},scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes`;

        var popup = window.open(url, "_blank", popupSettings);

        // Listen for changes in the URL
        var checkUrlInterval = setInterval(function () {
            if (popup && popup.location.href !== url) {
                // The URL has changed, perform actions after the redirect
                handleUrlChanged(popup.location.href);
                
                popup.close();

                clearInterval(checkUrlInterval);
            }
        }, 500);
    }

    function handleUrlChanged(newUrl) {
        // Extract the ID token from the new URL
        var idToken = extractIdTokenFromUrl(newUrl);

        if (idToken) {
            console.log('ID Token:', idToken);
        } else {
            console.log('ID Token not available');
        }
    }

    function extractIdTokenFromUrl(url) {
        var match = url.match(/[?&]id-token=([^&]*)/);
        return match ? match[1] : null;
    }
```

Comment: Which is the line that generates the error?

Comment: Sounds like the Same Origin Policy was doing its job, preventing you from "stealing" a token in a context were you _should_ not have access to it.

Comment: Seems **postMessage** can help. Something like `popup.postMessage({ token: extractIdTokenFromUrl(popup.location.href) }`

Comment: @AliSheikhpour the issue is, I don't have access to make any code changes in the app that runs in the pop up window. Any other alternative?